# Limit PHP-FPM memory consumption

Tags: php-fpm, memory-usage

In my php5-fpm/php.ini I have:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

However, after serving a few requests, `ps uxa` shows:

```
root      1130  0.0  0.3 339892  8064 ?        Ss   05:29   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)      
app       1131  0.6 38.9 1383692 798240 ?      S    05:29   0:50 php-fpm: pool www                                         
app       1132  0.7 38.6 1383656 792736 ?      S    05:29   0:57 php-fpm: pool www
```

798M RSS is quite beyond the limit. How is this possible? I could set a ulimit in the php-fpm init scripts, but first I would like to understand why it currently doesn't work.

Running php5-fpm 5.4.26 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**update** Thanks to OMG-1's answer below, I got it to work using this line in php-fpm.conf.

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M
```

Note: updating php.ini for 256M did result in an updated value according to `phpinfo()`, but not updated behaviour (even after reboot) -- I was still able to allocate 500M using the script below. So clearly a bug in PHP.

This was my test script, ([thank you SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944860/valid-memory-limit-test)).

```
<pre>
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

function tryAlloc($megabyte){
    echo "try allocating {$megabyte} megabyte...";
    $dummy = str_repeat("-",1048576*$megabyte);
    echo "pass.";
    echo "Usage: " . memory_get_usage(true)/1048576; 
    echo " Peak: " . memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1048576;
    echo "\n";
}   
for($i=10;$i<1000;$i+=50){
    $limit = $i.'M';
    ini_set('memory_limit', $limit); 
    echo "set memory_limit to {$limit}\n"; 
    echo "memory limit is ". ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
    tryAlloc($i-10);
}

?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962634/nginx-or-php-fpm-ignores-memory-limit-in-php-ini

I've never seen it work, when I put in memory limits in php.ini with php-fpm, I always use the php-fpm.conf and they are supposed to work.

Please verify that your master pool and using php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M works as expected?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed you are right: changing it in php.ini doesn't work, _even though the changed value was represented correctly in phpinfo()_.